# Why do I have a directory listing on my project when it's not on a web server, and how can I disable it

Tags: webserver, directory-listing

When I visit my project on http://localhost:8080/, instead of taking me to the homepage it takes me to a directory listing of all my files. When I look up how to disable it every solution has to do with different web servers, but my project isn't being hosted on a web server. In fact it isn't even deployed online, so I'm not sure what I can do to disable it.

Comment: `but my project isn't being hosted on a web server.` _Something_ has to respond to those web requests. __Thats__ the web server.

Comment: @tkausl how can I find out what web server it is